Selenium/C# - Clicking an Image - One Method Works, One Does Not -- Why?
I am trying to click this image..
<td width="1"><img style="cursor:pointer;" alt="" src="/App/Shared/Images/GridImages/Pager/first.gif" height="20" width="20" onclick="ctl05_gridMain.Page(0);return false;"></td>

This method works!
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr/td[1]/img[1]")).Click();

This method does not?!  The element is found, but is not interactable.
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[contains(@src, 'first.gif')]")).Click();

Why is this?

What's the exact exception?

element not interactable
